# Free-JQGrid Multiselect toolbar to refreshing when reloading data from server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have the below code and when I make a call back to the server to reload the grid, my drop down filters are not refreshing based on the column data.

Upon page load, the grid loads fine and the drop down filters are loaded with the appropriate data, excluding quotes that are in a canceled or expired status.  When the user clicks on the Canceled checkbox, the grid reloads and the data now includes the canceled status.  The issue is the status name drop down toolbar filter now does not include the new status of canceled (or expired if selected).  From what I can find online, it looks like the drop down filters should reload based on the new data. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ckRecentViewed").on('change', function (e) {
        loadGrid();
    });

    $("#ckCanceled").on('change', function (e) {
        loadGrid();
    });

    $("#ckExpired").on('change', function (e) {
        loadGrid();
    });

    $("input:radio:checked").data("chk", true);
    $("input:radio").click(function () {
        $("input[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']:radio").not(this).removeData("chk");
        $(this).data("chk", !$(this).data("chk"));
        $(this).prop("checked", $(this).data("chk"));
        $(this).button('refresh'); // in case you change the radio elements dynamically
        loadGrid();
    });

    $("#chkInMyStep").on('change', function (e) {
        loadGrid();
    });

    $('#dvWrapperFilter').on('click', function () {
        $("#dvFilters").slideToggle(function () {
            if ($('#imgHdrPlusMinus').attr('src').indexOf("plus") > 0) {
                $('#imgHdrPlusMinus').attr('src', $('#imgHdrPlusMinus').attr('src').replace("plus", "minus"));
            } else {
                $('#imgHdrPlusMinus').attr('src', $('#imgHdrPlusMinus').attr('src').replace("minus", "plus"));
            }
        });
    });
});

var statusIds = '0,1,3,4,5,6';

var cols = [
    { index: 'CTSID', name: 'CTSID', align: 'left', sortable: true, search: true, width: '20%' },
    { index: 'CustomerName', name: 'CustomerName', align: 'left', sortable: true, search: true, width: '60%' },
    { label: 'Terr', index: 'Territory', name: 'Territory', align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true, width: '20%' },
    { label: 'Zone Manager', index: 'CZMName', name: 'CZMName', align: 'left', sortable: true, search: true, width: '50%' },
    { label: 'Status', index: 'StatusName', name: 'StatusName', align: 'left', sortable: true, width: '30%' },
    { label: 'Version', index: 'VersionNumber', name: 'VersionNumber', align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true, width: '18%' },
    { label: 'Workflow Step', index: 'WorkflowName', name: 'WorkflowName', align: 'left', sortable: true, width: '30%' },
    {
        label: 'Expiration Date', index: 'EffectiveEndDate', name: 'EffectiveEndDate', sortable: true, width: '40%', sorttype: "date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/y" }, align: 'center',
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["eq"], // or any other search operation
            dataInit: function (element) {
                var self = this; // save the reference to the grid
                $(element).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    onSelect: function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            self.triggerToolbar();
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    {
        label: '', index: 'action', name: 'action', sortable: false, align: 'center', search: false, width: '20%', formatter: addLink, cellattr: function () {
            return "title=\"Click to view quote details\"";
        }
    }
];

var actionUrl = 'Dashboard/GetUserWorkflowDashboard';

var getUniqueNames = function (columnName, mydata) {
    var texts = $.map(mydata, function (item) {
        return item[columnName];
    }),
        uniqueTexts = [], textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;

    for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
        text = texts[i];
        if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
            // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
            textsMap[text] = true;
            uniqueTexts.push(text);
        }
    }
    return uniqueTexts;
},
    buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
        var values = "";
        $.each(uniqueNames, function () {
            values += this + ":" + this + ";";
        });
        return values.slice(0, -1);
    },
    initMultiselect = function (searchOptions) {
        var $elem = $(searchOptions.elem),
            options = {
                selectedList: 2,
                height: "auto",
                checkAllText: "all",
                uncheckAllText: "no",
                noneSelectedText: "Any",
                open: function () {
                    var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                    $menu.addClass("ui-jqdialog").width("auto");
                    $menu.find(">ul").css("maxHeight", "200px");
                }
            };
        if (searchOptions.mode === "filter") {
            options.minWidth = "auto";
        }
        $elem.multiselect(options);
        $elem.siblings("button.ui-multiselect").css({
            width: "100%",
            margin: "1px 0",
            paddingTop: ".3em",
            paddingBottom: "0"
        });
    },
    setSearchSelect = function (columnName, data) {
        var values = buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call(this, columnName, data));
        $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", columnName, {
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                value: values,
                sopt: ["in"],
                attr: {
                    multiple: "multiple",
                    size: 4
                },
                selectFilled: initMultiselect
            }
        });
    },
    myDefaultSearch = "cn",

beforeProcessingHandler1 = function (data) {
    var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    // !!! it will be called only after loading from the server
    // datatype is always "json" here
    setSearchSelect.call(this, "WorkflowName", data);
    setSearchSelect.call(this, "StatusName", data);
    setSearchSelect.call(this, "CZMName", data);

    if (this.ftoolbar === true) {
        //if the filter toolbar is not already created
        $("#gs_" + this.id + "WorkflowName").multiselect("destroy");
        $this.jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar');

        $("#gs_" + this.id + "StatusName").multiselect("destroy");
        $this.jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar');

        $("#gs_" + this.id + "CZMName").multiselect("destroy");
        $this.jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar');
    }

    if (p.postData.filters) {
        p.search = true;
    }

    $this.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
        stringResult: true,
        defaultSearch: myDefaultSearch,
        beforeClear: function () {
            $(this.grid.hDiv)
                .find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect")
                .each(function () {
                    $(this).prev("select[multiple]").multiselect("refresh");
                });
            $(this.grid.hDiv)
                .find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect")
                .each(function () {
                    // synchronize jQuery UI Multiselect with <select>
                    $(this).prev("select[multiple]").multiselect("refresh");
                }
                ).css({
                    width: "98%",
                    marginTop: "1px",
                    marginBottom: "1px",
                    paddingTop: "3px"
                });
        }
    });
};

$(function () {
    //Initialize jqgrid
    $("#gridWorkflowDashboard").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: actionUrl,
        mType: 'GET',
        colModel: cols,
        rowList: [25, 50, 100],
        pager: "#dvDashboardPager",
        forceClientSorting: true,
        loadonce: true,
        beforeProcessing: beforeProcessingHandler1,
        sortname: "EffectiveEndDate",
        sorttype: "date",
        sortorder: "desc",
        rownumbers: false,
        rowNum: 25,
        gridview: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        height: "100%",
        autowidth: true,
        search: true,
        altclass: "GridRows",
        recreateFilter: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true });
});

function loadGrid() {
    page = $("#gridWorkflowDashboard").getGridParam('page');
    var ids = statusIds;

    var pExperationDate = $('input:radio[name="rdExpiration"]:checked').val();
    var pToDate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
    var pFromDate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
    var pRecentView = $("#ckRecentViewed")[0].checked;
    var pInMyStep = $("#chkInMyStep")[0].checked;
    var pCanceled = $("#ckCanceled")[0].checked;
    var pExpired = $("#ckExpired")[0].checked;

    if (pCanceled) {
        ids += ',-1';
    }
    else {
        ids = statusIds;
    }

    if (pExpired) {
        ids += ',2';
    }
    else {
        ids = statusIds;

        if (pCanceled) {
            ids += ',-1';
        }
    }

    var data = { ExperationDays: pExperationDate, toDate: pToDate, fromDate: pFromDate, recentView: pRecentView, InMyStep: pInMyStep, StatusIds: ids };

    $.ajax(actionUrl, {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        loadonce: true,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#gridWorkflowDashboard").jqGrid('clearGridData');
            //$("#gridWorkflowDashboard").jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar');
            $("#gridWorkflowDashboard").jqGrid('setGridParam',
                {
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data: result
                }).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: page }]);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<input type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs grid-btn' value='View' onclick='ViewQuote(\"" + rowObject.CTSID + "\")'\>";
}

function ViewQuote(value) {
    window.location.href = '/CPQ/Quote/EditQuote/' + value;
}

$(function () {
    $("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        minDate: "-8Y",
        maxDate: "0Y",
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            loadGrid();
        }
    }); 

    $("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        minDate: "-8Y",
        maxDate: "0Y",
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            loadGrid();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how free-jqGrid work (we support Guriddo jqGrid), but I think you should first destroy the filterToolbar before to create it again. When created the filter toolbar set a flag which indicate its existing. Any other call to it will not execute. So maybe to work this you should call destroyFilterToolbar before to create it.

```
beforeProcessingHandler1 = function (data) {
....
    $this.jqGrid("destroyFilterToolba");
    $this.jqGrid("filterToolbar",{...});
}
```

Personally maybe I will refresh the select values directly in the toolbar with jQuery functions, but this depend on your implementation.

Comment: Hi Tony.  I have tried your suggestion and I can see the data changing but it looks like the overall grid does not seem to be refreshing.  I even set the loadonce option to false.

Comment: Not sure I understand the: "..I can see the data changing but it looks like the overall grid does not seem to be refreshing." What you mean with this? Please explain.

Comment: I put together a sample but for some reason I am unable to get the same to load my test data.  But at least you can see a good part of my code and what I am trying to do.  So when I comment about the data changing, I was clicking on the "Canceled" checkbox and that would reload the data with only a canceled status.  What I was hoping to achieve is that the grid filters would reload and only display "Canceled".  (I know it doesn't make sense but that is what is what I have been asked to do.)       [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/JMK123/30gkj78f/31/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is free-jqGrid. We support Guriddo jqGrid,  so the only way to help in this case is really to prepare a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching over to Guriddo jqGrid since i found more documentation and helpful examples and was able to solve my issue.  Thanks for your help Tony.